# Is the homomorphism induced on symmetric algebras injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a (nonzero) commutative ring with $1$.

Suppose $f: A^n \longrightarrow A^m$ is an injective homomorphism of $A$ -modules. (This implies $n\leq m$.)

Then is it true that the induced map on symmetric algebras

$$\operatorname{Sym}A^n \longrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}A^m$$

is injective?

In other words, if $\varphi: A[x_1,...,x_n]\longrightarrow A[y_1,...,y_m]$ is a homomorphism of **graded** $A$-algebras, and if $\varphi(x_1),...,\varphi(x_n)$
 are linearly independent over $A$, then is $\varphi$ injective?

Thanks.

**Remark:**

This is true for $n=m$, as then $\operatorname{det}f$ is a non-zero divisor;

also, it is so for $n=1$!!

It seems to be true for $A$ reduced.

Comment: One way of proving this is finding a general projection $A^m\to A^n$ so that the composite $A^n\to A^n$ is injective and then use your remark.

Comment: There would NOT exist such a projection, because injectivity of $f$  implies that the annihilator of the ideal generated by $n \times n$-minors is zero, but this does NOT mean there is an $n \times n$-minor which is a non-zero divisor.

Comment: I said general projection, not with the given basis.

Comment: So you mean that there is an $n\times m$-matrix $g$ s.t. $\operatorname{det} (g\cdot f)$ is a non-zero divisor, right? How can I prove it?